# Facing issue: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 918: ordinal not in range(128) while trying to load a Pytorch model

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I am trying to load a pre-trained Pytorch model but getting an error as shown below:

```
model = torch.load('a.pth')
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 267, in load
    return _load(f, map_location, pickle_module)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 420, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 918: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am using Python 3.6 in the virtual environment and PyTorch version = 0.3.1, any leads towards resolving the issue will be helpful.

Comment: Do you know which version of python is used to save `a.pth`?

Answer (score 1):

From documentation:

> By default, we decode byte strings as utf-8. This is to avoid a common error case UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x... when loading files saved by Python 2 in Python 3. If this default is incorrect, you may use an extra encoding keyword argument to specify how these objects should be loaded, e.g., encoding='latin1' decodes them to strings using latin1 encoding, and encoding='bytes' keeps them as byte arrays which can be decoded later with byte_array.decode(...).

Try to change encoding, for instance:

```
model = torch.load('a.pth', encoding='latin')  # or 'ascii'
```

Comment: Hey @Corralien thanks for the reply, I did try it out but got the following error: 

model = torch.load('a.pth',map_location ='cpu',encoding='latin')
TypeError: load() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

;looks like there is no argument named encoding for pytorch load

Comment: The latest version of `torch` is 1.9.0... Could you update your version?

Comment: I did try that first, the pre-trained model I have was trained on earlier versions of pytorch. Though for 1.9.0 it gets loaded properly and I am able to get the model summary too, I faced some issues later on that forced me to revert back to 0.3.1.

Comment: Try to use `pickle` or `joblib` package firstly to try to load the object inside the file.